# Bind Data to a Label MVC4

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm going to bind data to a label using MVC4,But it's not success..Data come to model.
Here is my code.

```
<div class="newclass">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NewsTeam.NewsMgr, new { style = "width:100%", @class = "newcssval" })
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => Model.NewsTeam.NewsMgr)
```

or use DisplayFor

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.NewsTeam.NewsMgr)
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

This will only give you the name of the field (or it's display value from the class). I suspect what you need is the following.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NewsTeam.NewsMgr,
                            new { @class = "newcssval", @readonly = true })
```

This will give you a read-only text box wuth the content of your model data.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

If your intent is to simply show the value of the property, use the `Display` or `DisplayFor` helper:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.NewsTeam.NewsMgr)
```

Or, forget the helper entirely:

```
@Model.NewsTeam.NewsMgr
```

If the property contains HTML, you'll need to use the `Raw` helper:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.NewsTeam.NewsMgr)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this,

@Model.NewsTeam.NewsMgr
It will just show the value of property as label

Or Use,

@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.NewsTeam.NewsMgr)